# Running system("dpkg-deb -b test"); doesn't work

Tags: php, deb, dpkg

I'm trying to build a `.deb` file with PHP.

I've got an example directory called "test"; when I run `dpkg-b "test"` in my local Terminal, it works fine, but in PHP it doesn't.

My code is:

```
system("dpkg-deb -b test");
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What does it do instead of work?

Comment: Nothin... No Deb-file appears